# php : retrive and display data from different table in db

Tags: php, mysql

I have two `tables` (`room`, `category`) in my database. `room` table consists of `room_id`, `room_name`, and `room_image`. `category` table consists of `category_id`, `room_id`, `category_name` and `category_image`.

My index page displayed 3 types of rooms. When I choose to click a room, 3 different categories should be displayed at each of the room. However, none of the categories was displayed.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","homefurniture");

function getRoom(){

global $con;

$get_room = "select * from room";

$run_room = mysqli_query($con, $get_room);

while ($row_room = mysqli_fetch_array($run_room)){

    $room_id = $row_room['room_id'];
    $room_name = $row_room ['room_name'];
    $room_image = $row_room['room_image'];

echo "<div class='col-md-4 about-left'>


                <figure class='effect-bubba'>



                    <a href = 'category.php?room=$room_id'>
                   <img class='img-responsive' src='images/$room_image' alt=''/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>$room_name</h2>

                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>
            </div>
    ";
    }
}

function getRoomCat(){

$room_id = $_SESSION['roomid'];
global $con; 

$get_room_cat = "select * from category where room_id='".$room_id."'";

$run_room_cat = mysqli_query($con, $get_room_cat); 
while($row_room_cat=mysqli_fetch_array($run_room_cat)){

$category_id = $row_room_cat['category_id'];
$room_id = $row_room_cat['room_id'];
$category_name = $row_room_cat['category_name'];
$category_image = $row_room_cat['category_image'];



    echo "
             <h1>$room_name</h1><p></p>
        <div class='about-top grid-1'>
            <div class='col-md-4 about-left'>
                <figure class='effect-bubba'>
                    <a href= 'product.php?pro_id=$pro_id'>
                    <img class='img-responsive' src='images/$category_image' alt=''/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h4>$category_name</h4>

                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
    ";
    }
}
```

Comment: When you are storing room id into session ?

Comment: also missing session_start

Comment: try to debug your code by printing room id and also check when you are reteriving the data from the database that whether categories exist for particular room or not